# Manipular JSON devuelto por AJAX para busqueda

Tags: jquery

En las altas de mi sistema quiero comprobar si un producto o cliente,etc existe.
Para no usar el servidor lo cual es una carga, quiero traer los datos en JSON y recorrer el array para saber si el nombre de cliente existe, no insertarlo:

Nuevo codigo:

```js
function existe(nombre){
  accion="listar";
  $.ajax({
   
    type: "POST",
    url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
    data: { "accion": accion}, 
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(){
        alert("error petición ajax");
    },
    success: function(filtrado){
      var fil = filtrado.filter(function(e){
        return e.nombre==nombre;
      });
      console.log(fil.length);
      if (fil.length==0){
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

En el codigo de arriba traigo el array todo bien, de hecho tengo una tabla donde lo muestro.
Luego hago:

```
$("#guardar").click(function(){
    var CUIT=$("#cuit1").val();
    var deuda=0;
    var telfijo=$("#Fijo").val();
    var celular=$("#Celular").val();
    var nombre=$("#Nombre").val();
    var direccion=$("#domicilio").val();
    var civa=$("#iva").val();

    if (nombre===''){
      alert("ingrese un nombre valido");
    }else if (existe(nombre)==true){
      alert("el cliente ya esta registrado");
    }else{
      alert(nombre); alert(existe(nombre));
      $.ajax({

    //codigo de insertar
```

¿Es esta la forma correcta o mejor es php? Si se puede con jquery como hago para mantener los datos en un array, porque el problema es que content llega vacío.

Gracias

Comment: El `content.filter` tiene que ir dentro de la funcion `success`

Comment: lo agrega igual, existe(nombre) devuelve undefined

Comment: Como dice @alanfcm, debes manejar los datos que te trae Ajax dentro de `success`, o pasarlos de ahí a la otra función, dado que Ajax es asíncrono. Hay que ver también la estructura del JSON que estás devolviendo desde el servidor. Puedes mostrar su contenido en la consola. `success: function(filtrado){
                console.log(filtrado);
               
                }`  Por ejemplo si el JSON está bien, el valor del nombre podrás obtenerlo haciendo esto: `filtrado.nombre`

Comment: Edite la pregunta con el codigo de filtrado dentro de success. no se que esta mal. fil.length devuelve mas de 0 lo cual esta bien.

Comment: Pregunta: ¿seguro que quieres mandar toda la información al cliente? Sería mejor si mandaras el ID/nombre del cliente en la petición y el filtrado lo realizaras en el lado del servidor. De lo contrario, un usuario con poca experiencia sería capaz de ver los datos de todos tus clientes (al menos el nombre, no sé si algún dato más). Algo que me imagino no quieres. Además, al mandar todos los datos, tu operación será muy costosa (mayor tiempo de proceso en el servidor, en el cliente, y de tráfico de datos), especialmente si tienes muchos clientes.

Comment: Ok voy a intentar ese metodo.